# How do I retrieve only record which has `SUM(if(release = 'ER_APR15',1,0)) AS 'GROUP6' > 0`?

Tags: mysql

I have following two tables:

1. `tblscr_role Field: scr_roleid, role, requestid`
2. `scrs Field: requestid, release`

I have existing following `query`:

```
SELECT 
    `role` as 'Role Name', 
    SUM(if(`release` = 'ER_APR15',1,0)) AS 'ER_APR15', 
    SUM(if(`release` = 'ER_APR15',1,0)) AS 'ER_JUNE15', 
    SUM(if(`release` = 'ER_APR15',1,0)) AS 'GROUP6' 
from scrs, tblscr_role 
Where (scrs.requestid = tblscr_role.requestid) 
    and (role Like '%:XX%') 
    and `release` IN ( 'ER_APR15', 'ER_JUNE15', 'GROUP6') 
GROUP BY `role`;
```

1. How do I retrieve only record which has `SUM(if(release = 'ER_APR15',1,0)) AS 'GROUP6' > 0`?
2. If I have below SQL and I want to have a result where any of the two column have more that value 0, how can I do that?

Query:

```
SELECT 
 `role` AS 'Role Name', 
 SUM( if( `release` = 'ER_APR15', 1, 0 ) ) AS 'ER_APR15', 
 SUM( if( `release` = 'ER_JUNE15', 1, 0 ) ) AS 'ER_JUNE15', 
 SUM( if( `release` = 'GROUP6', 1, 0 ) ) AS 'GROUP6' 
FROM scrs, tblscr_role 
WHERE (scrs.requestid = tblscr_role.requestid) 
 AND (role LIKE '%:XX%') 
 AND `release` IN ( 'ER_APR15', 'ER_JUNE15', 'GROUP6') 
GROUP BY `role` 
HAVING ((SUM( if( `release` = 'ER_APR15', 1, 0 ) ) >0) 
 OR (SUM( if( `release` = 'ER_JUNE15', 1, 0 ) ) >0) 
 OR (SUM( if( `release` = 'GROUP6', 1, 0 ) ) >0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `having` ;

```
SELECT  
    `role`  as 'Role Name', 
    SUM(if(`release` = 'ER_APR15',1,0)) AS 'ER_APR15', 
    SUM(if(`release` = 'ER_APR15',1,0)) AS 'ER_JUNE15', 
    SUM(if(`release` = 'ER_APR15',1,0)) AS 'GROUP6' 
from scrs, tblscr_role 
Where (scrs.requestid = tblscr_role.requestid) 
    and (role Like '%:XX%') 
    and `release` IN ( 'ER_APR15', 'ER_JUNE15', 'GROUP6') 
GROUP BY `role`
having SUM(if(release = 'ER_APR15',1,0)) > 0
```

You can use subquery too..

```
Select * 
from (
    Your_query_without_having
) as x
Where GROUP6 > 0
```

For second question:

Any two columns having value `> 0`:

```
SELECT 
    role AS 'Role Name', 
    SUM( if( release = 'ER_APR15', 1, 0 ) ) AS 'ER_APR15', 
    SUM( if( release = 'ER_JUNE15', 1, 0 ) ) AS 'ER_JUNE15', 
    SUM( if( release = 'GROUP6', 1, 0 ) ) AS 'GROUP6' 
FROM scrs, tblscr_role 
WHERE (scrs.requestid = tblscr_role.requestid) 
    AND (role LIKE '%:XX%') 
    AND release IN ( 'ER_APR15', 'ER_JUNE15', 'GROUP6') 
GROUP BY role 
HAVING (
    SUM( if( release = 'ER_APR15', 1, 0 ) ) >0 and
    SUM( if( release = 'ER_JUNE15', 1, 0 ) ) >0 
)
or (
    SUM( if( release = 'ER_APR15', 1, 0 ) ) >0 and
    SUM( if( release = 'GROUP6', 1, 0 ) ) >0
) 
or (
    SUM( if( release = 'ER_JUNE15', 1, 0 ) ) >0 and
    SUM( if( release = 'GROUP6', 1, 0 ) ) >0
)
```

or using `sub query`:

```
Select * 
from (
    Your_query_without_having
) as x
Where (
    ER_APR15 > 0 and
    ER_JUNE15 > 0 
)
or (
    ER_APR15 > 0 and
    GROUP6 > 0
) 
or (
    ER_JUNE15 > 0 and
    GROUP6 > 0
);
```

Comment: If I have below SQL and I want to have a result where any of the two coulum have more that value 0, how can I do that ?